# No breadcrumb for custom view in Sonata Admin?

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, breadcrumbs, sonata

I created a custom view in Sonata Admin following recipe from official doc ([here](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/cookbook/recipe_custom_view.html)).

Everything is working good, but breadcrumb is empty (the same in last screenshot of recipe).

I googled a lot without success... Isn't it possible to display breadcrumbs with custom views in Sonata Admin?

Answer (score 1):

I achieved this by extending sonata_breadcrumb block:

```
{% block sonata_breadcrumb %}
    <div class="hidden-xs">
        <ol class="nav navbar-top-links breadcrumb">
            <li>
                <a href="/admin">
                    <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="active">
                <span>My Custom View</span>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </div>
{% endblock sonata_breadcrumb %}
```

Can someone confirm it's the right way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Another option to show a custom breadcrumb is to define a block for it, like this:

```
{% extends '@SonataAdmin/standard_layout.html.twig' %}

{% block breadcrumb %}
<li>
    <a href="/admin/dashboard">
        <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
    </a>
</li>
<li class="active">
    <span>My Profile</span>
</li>
{% endblock %}

{#
More HTML/Twig code
#}
```